# Cannot count on subquery and get proper results.Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**I have two tables:**

Advertisement(***ano***, newspaper, pno)

Property(***pno***, street, suburb, post, first_list, type, peid)

My goal is to list the properties that have been advertised in at least 2 different newspapers.

Currently I have tried these two queries:

```
SELECT P.pno, P.suburb, P.type
FROM (SELECT pno, newspaper
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT pno, newspaper 
            FROM advertisement)
            GROUP BY pno, newspaper) SQ1, property P, advertisement A
WHERE P.pno = A.pno AND SQ1.pno = P.pno
GROUP BY P.pno, P.suburb, P.type
HAVING COUNT(SQ1.pno) > 1
;
```

and

```
SELECT P.pno, P.suburb, P.type
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT pno
      FROM  advertisement 
      GROUP BY pno
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) A1
      LEFT JOIN property P ON P.pno = A1.pno;
```

which gives the following results:

[image]

So the problem with my queries are they are not accounting for properties advertised in the same newspaper twice. They both return every property advertised more than once. The rogue property here is pno = 40. It is listed twice, but in the same newspaper.

When I run the subquery it gives me the pno without duplicates.

**Example:**

This is the advertisement table.

[image]

and this is the result of the subquery.

[image]

So the goal is to count only the pno in the subquery that exist more than once, > 1 at this point. I have spent more time on this one issue than I care to admit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you really try queries that begin with the keyword `FROM`? In Oracle SQL? And that didn't throw an error? Or are those **not** the queries you ran, but perhaps just parts of them? Please clarify.

Comment: @mathguy Was problem with code ``` the select statements were there just not displayed.

Comment: That is not true. Please click on the "edited ... ago" link, next to the "asked ... ago" marker at the bottom of your post. If you click on the "edited" link you can see the history of the post. There was no "select" clause in your earlier versions of the post, you just added that in your last edit. Please don't distort the truth here.

Comment: @mathguy Beleive what you want, but the original document had:
``` SELECT ......

Which needed to have the SELECT one line below the ```

Comment: I don't believe what I want, I believe what I see. Did you review the history of your post, as I suggested? Do you see what YOU are claiming, anywhere there? Or are you saying that the history is somehow wrong, maybe someone changed your post in the history? (Note - no one, not even the site managers, can edit THAT.)

Comment: @mathguy Also, where did I distort the truth? Read my comment again if you did not comprehend it, but it clearly states "they were there, just not displayed" as in not displayed in the earlier versions. I updated the post with the SELECT staement below the ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query which is using aggregation with distinct clause -

```
SELECT P.pno, P.street, P.suburb, P.post, P.first_list, P.type, P.peid
  FROM Advertisement AD
  JOIN Property P ON P.pno = AD.pno
 GROUP BY P.pno, P.street, P.suburb, P.post, P.first_list, P.type, P.peid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AD.newspaper) > 1
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you so much! Not sure why I didn't think of counting the newspapers instead of the pno.